# SSIS 2008 gets stuck after error on execute sql task

Tags: ssis

I am working on this SSIS package and I purposely made an error on the execute sql task to test the failure precedence constraint but it gets stuck on the execute sql task where the error is. It should follow the failure precedence and execute the next step when it encounters an error.

Basically, the error on the execute sql task is I was truncating a table that does not exists...in real life, it happens maybe because of a typo error.

I have already set the delayvalidation to true but it is still not working.

http://i69.photobucket.com/albums/i47/boxingpics/Untitled-2.jpg

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that in the Precedence Constraint Editor dialog, you selected "Logical OR. One constraint must evaluate to True." If this is already selected, can you provide a screenshot of the constraint dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have provided the link on my post. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I edited my first comment with the likely culprit. I'm specifically asking for the dialog that appears when you right-click the precedence constraint and choose "Edit...".

Comment: Hey @dev_etter, it worked! I am a little new to this. Thanks for your help and time! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, now I will add my comment as an answer and provide a little more detail.

Comment: erwin Welcome to StackOverflow!  Now that @dev_etter has answered your question, you should mark it as the answer for your problem so that other users can seach and find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Precedence Constraint Editor dialog (right-click on the precedence constraint and choose "Edit..."), select "Logical OR. One constraint must evaluate to True."

[Working with Precedence Constraints in SSIS](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/):

> Logical AND: All precedence constraints that point to the constrained executable must evaluate to true in order for that executable to run. This is the default option. If it is selected, the arrow is solid.
>
> Logical OR: Only one precedence constraint that points to the constrained executable must evaluate to true in order for that executable to run. If this option is selected, the arrow is dotted.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue and have resolved it by doing the following:

1. Add a package level variable, ErrorCount of type Int
2. Add an OnError Event Handler to your Execute SQL Task and create a Script Task.

   2.a  This script task should take the ErrorCount variable as a ReadWriteVariable

   2.b  In the definition of the script you can do the following:

   ```
   public void Main() {
       Dts.Variables["User::ErrorCount"].Value = int.Parse(Dts.Variables["User::ErrorCount"].Value.ToString()) + 1;
       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   }
   ```
3. Then in your failure precedence constraint, you will want to set it using the following settings:

   Evaluation Operation: **Expression and Constraint**

   Value: **Failure**

   Expression: **@[User::ErrorCount] > 0**

   Multiple Constraints: **Logical Or**

Hope that this helps